# CentOS 7 httpd failed to make connection with backend

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, ssl, tomcat, reverse-proxy

In a `CentOS 7` server with `apache httpd 2.4` set up as an `ssl reverse proxy` for `tomcat`, I am getting an error indicating that `httpd` is not able to connect with `tomcat`.  **How can I resolve this error so that httpd serves up the content generated by tomcat?**

The `ssl_error_log` says:

```
[Tue Dec 16 20:20:15.007630 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 12784] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Tue Dec 16 20:20:15.007727 2014] [proxy:error] [pid 12784] AH00959: ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost) for 60s
[Tue Dec 16 20:20:15.007752 2014] [proxy_http:error] [pid 12784] [client client.ip.address:48100] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: localhost
```

I have read the `catalina.out` file, which clearly indicates that `tomcat` successfully launched the root app after I ran `startup.sh`.  I also read [this other posting](http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/), which put the blame on `SELinux`.  But I made sure that `/etc/sysconfig/selinux` has `SELINUX=disabled`, so it seems my problem is caused by something else.

The `reverse proxy` was working perfectly earlier today.  The only changes made on the server today were to upload new versions of the root war into `tomcat` a couple of times, and to stop then `restart tomcat` and `httpd` each time a new root war was uploaded.  This might have involved changing the `shutdown port` in `server.xml` from -1 to a valid port number to allow `tomcat` to shutdown.

You can view the complete `ssl.conf` [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/UbYqXL6SWRyeeMbrhYzJ?b=kpc6vajMUHbPjrnIrwHs).  Please note that the `VirtualHost` is completely defined in `ssl.conf` and NOT in `httpd.conf`.  You can also read the complete `server.xml` [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/bNKKxAwWUaKOUUKpnePw?b=8cUyiz6AhMFv03bK0jSu).

**EDIT:**

Following IanMcGowan's advice gave the following results:

```
[root@remote.server.ip ~]# telnet localhost 8080
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: connect to address 127.0.0.1: Connection refused
[root@remote.server.ip ~]# GET / HTTP/1.0
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Directory /</TITLE>
<BASE HREF="file:/">
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Directory listing of /</H1>
<UL>
<LI><A HREF="./">./</A>
<LI><A HREF="../">../</A>
<LI><A HREF=".autorelabel">.autorelabel</A>
<LI><A HREF=".readahead">.readahead</A>
<LI><A HREF="bin/">bin/</A>
<LI><A HREF="boot/">boot/</A>
<LI><A HREF="db/">db/</A>
<LI><A HREF="dev/">dev/</A>
<LI><A HREF="etc/">etc/</A>
<LI><A HREF="home/">home/</A>
<LI><A HREF="lib/">lib/</A>
<LI><A HREF="lib64/">lib64/</A>
<LI><A HREF="media/">media/</A>
<LI><A HREF="mnt/">mnt/</A>
<LI><A HREF="opt/">opt/</A>
<LI><A HREF="proc/">proc/</A>
<LI><A HREF="root/">root/</A>
<LI><A HREF="run/">run/</A>
<LI><A HREF="sbin/">sbin/</A>
<LI><A HREF="srv/">srv/</A>
<LI><A HREF="sys/">sys/</A>
<LI><A HREF="tmp/">tmp/</A>
<LI><A HREF="usr/">usr/</A>
<LI><A HREF="var/">var/</A>
<LI><A HREF="www/">www/</A>
</UL>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

I also opened up 8080 to test if tomcat is running as follows:

When I typed in `http : / / mydomain.com` and `http : / / my.ip.address` , nothing was served to the browser.  When I type `https : / / mydomain.com` , I get the same error stating the service is unavailable.

The last two lines of `catalina.out` have not changed since I restarted the server yesterday, and are as follows:

```
16-Dec-2014 20:19:35.967 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.start$
16-Dec-2014 20:19:35.970 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start$ Server startup in 46065 ms
```

**EDIT #2:**

To test if tomcat is running, I did the following:

```
[root@remote.server.ip]# ps aux | grep tomcat
root      6858  0.7 18.5 3826248 1095780 ?     Sl   Dec12  51:03 java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     12524  0.2 20.1 3891788 1187888 ?     Sl   Dec15   6:20 java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     16404  0.2 15.0 3630784 887836 ?      Sl   Dec16   2:36 java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/tomcat/endorsed -classpath /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/opt/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/opt/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root     17987  0.0  0.0 112640   964 pts/0    R+   14:20   0:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

Comment: Are you sure tomcat is running?  A common problem at startup is that something is already listening on a port it needs (e.g. your 8005 shutdown port).  Can you post the complete catalina.out? You do not have to restart tomcat when making changes to the Apache proxy.

Comment: "telnet localhost 8080" from a shell on the CentOS server to make sure that tomcat is listening.  If telnet gives an error, you are not connected, if nothing appears tomcat is up.  You can type "GET / HTTP/1.0[enter][enter]" to request the default page.

Comment: @IanMcGowan: +1, but you shouldn't get "nothing" from `telnet` if Tomcat is up and running on port 8080. You'll get 3 or so lines, something like `Trying localhost...` then `Connected to localhost.` then `Escape character is ^]`. Also, `telnet` isn't installed by default on CentOS 7, so you may need to say `yum install telnet` first.

Comment: @WarrenYoung - you're right!  To my shame I was thinking of the windows telnet command.  On *nix I tend to use netcat nowadays...

Comment: @CodeMed: Why are you bringing a second computer into the discussion at all? The mantra of troubleshooting is to keep it as simple as possible, and test only one thing at a time. So, do *everything* here on a single machine. I don't care if you do it all on your development box or all on the production box. `telnet localhost 8080` only works *within* a single machine. That's what `localhost` means.

Comment: Why are you using generic proxying when there is a [specific solution](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/generic_howto/quick.html) designed to link Tomcat and Apache?

Comment: @IanMcGowan I posted the results of your `telnet` commands in an edit to my OP above.  I hesitate to post `catalina.out` because it is a massive file that really only shows that `tomcat` has loaded the app on the server, with no requests afterwards.  I will try to open `8080` to the world and access it by http to confirm `tomcat` is working.

Comment: @IanMcGowan I added the results of opening `port 8080`, along with the last 2 lines of of `catalina.out.`

Comment: @WarrenYoung please see the edit to my OP above.

Comment: Tomcat is not running, or is not listening on 127.0.0.1. Is there someone local who can help you with this? Stackoverflow is a Q/A site, not a troubleshooting service. Is this the best approach to getting your site running?

Comment: @IanMcGowan The server is on a hosting company's network. I only call them with the types of questions that help me trouble shoot myself. I got the server in order to learn it by trial and error. I have had success with many similar questions on SO over the years.

Comment: Can you post the output of: `cat /etc/sysconfig/network`?

Comment: @eyoung100 `cat /etc/sysconfig/network` produced only one single line of output as follows: `# Created by anaconda`

Comment: That's on your Devbox right?

Comment: @eyoung100 No. That (and everything else in this post) is on the remote web server. I did not intend any confusion. Everything works on my local machine.

Comment: Can you remove Tomcat and Catalina, and your reverse proxy, so we have a clean slate?

Comment: @eyoung100 If I remove tomcat and catalina, I am just going to have to rebuild the reverse proxy and ssl, which I need up and running tomorrow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19561/discussion-between-eyoung100-and-codemed).

Comment: @eyoung100 this site still will not let me log into chat, but we could talk on the SO chat room again if you are willing.  here is the link: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67058/private

Comment: It's easiest to 1. Get all the services you need running first then add the reverse proxy, then add the SSL, or 2. Setup the reverse proxy, add all your services, and hen add SSL.

Comment: @eyoung100 My host did a clean install of CentOS.  I installed httpd and tomcat.  The war is served by tomcat through 8080, but I am having trouble getting httpd to connect with tomcat.  Are you willing to look at this again?  I logged into this chat room: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67058/private

Comment: @eyoung100 Thank you for all the help you have given me.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @eyoung100 If you are still willing to help me with this, I am logged on to the server as root, and I am in the chat room reviewing what you typed before: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67058/private

Comment: @eyoung100 I did the digitalocean tutorial, and now it is giving me a different error about not being able to reliably resolve the servername.  I tried a few things that have not resolved the problem.  Not sure if I should rip everything out and start over, or if there is an easier way to resolve this new error. I have the chat room open while I am researching options.

Comment: @eyoung100 I wrote up the results of your changes to `/etc/hosts` as an edit to another question. If you would like to read it, this link is here:  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175558/apache-will-not-restart-after-adding-link-to-virtual-host-conf-file-why

Answer (score 9):

To fix this, first test by setting the boolean dynamically (not permanent yet):

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

If that works, you can set it so that the default policy is changed and this setting will persist across reboots:

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

Credit: https://web.archive.org/web/20190313023936/http://sysadminsjourney.com/content/2010/02/01/apache-modproxy-error-13permission-denied-error-rhel/

Comment: This worked for me on Fedora 29 as well.

Comment: Real MVP right here.