# httpd doesn't serve relative url from tomcat, why not?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, proxy, tomcat

In a `CentOS 7` server, I am trying to set up `httpd` to act as a `reverse proxy` for `tomcat`.  I have `httpd` running perfectly in the sense that I type in `http/mydomain.com` and it serves up static content located in the designated `DocumentRoot`.  I also have `tomcat` running perfectly in that `tomcat` serves up a designated `war` file when I type in `http/my.server.ip:8080`.  The `war` file redirects all unauthenticated users to the `/login` url pattern so they can sign in before using the site.  This works fine in `tomcat`.  But when I comment out the `DocumentRoot` and add `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` instead, I get the following error message in the browser:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /login.

Reason: DNS lookup failure for: server.ip.address:8009login
```

My `VirtualHost` is as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias mydomain.com
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_com_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/mydomain_com_requests.log combined
    ProxyPass / ajp://server.ip.address:8009
    ProxyPassReverse / ajp://server.ip.address:8009
</VirtualHost>
```

I also made sure to uncomment the following connector in `server.xml`:

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

You can read the entire `server.xml` file located in a file sharing site [by clicking on this link](https://jumpshare.com/v/sqHwmSycyZuWXg8ylscA?b=4VHAL6DX1Ak7pRJzkexO).

`Apache` is obviously talking to `tomcat` and working with the `war` file, because `apache` figured out how to get re-directed to the `/login` url pattern.  But **how can I fix my configuration so that /login and other relative urls get served correctly?**

I am not certain whether or not `mod_jk` is installed.

Comment: Glad you got all this working.  You're on the final step...  I must ask though: Where does login come from in `server.ip.address:8009login`

Comment: @eyoung100 When a user who has not been authenticated by the java application/war requests any url in the app, that user is redirected by the app to the `/login` url pattern.  In this case, the user is requesting the `/` url pattern.  But since the user has not logged in to the app yet, the request is redirected to `/login`.

Comment: Well then you forgot a space

Comment: @eyoung100 where?

Comment: `server.ip.address:8009login`  That string is not terminated properly  The server thinks the port is 8009login

Comment: @eyoung100 That makes perfect sense. I just do not know what to do with that information.

Comment: @eyoung100 I just tried adding a space after `ProxyPass / ajp://server.ip.address:8009 ` and after `ProxyPassReverse / ajp://server.ip.address:8009 `, then stopped and restarted httpd, but I get the same error.

Comment: Who or what is resolving your DNS?

Comment: @eyoung100 My domain registrar has `DNS` set up for me, pointing to this server's ip. But I do not know what is resolving them inside the `CentOS 7` box. I can tell you that `firewalld` has the `dhcpv6-client` service enabled.

Comment: Have you read the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)  I don't think ProxyPass can resolve to the root.

Comment: @garethTheRed That solved the problem.  Thank you very much. In american basketball, they call what you just did a 3 point shot, when the player nails it over long distance from the opposite side of the court. If you want to write it as an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted and +1.  Thank you.

Comment: There was more luck than skill in that 3 point shot, I'm afraid :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Append a `/` to both your `ProxyPass` lines as it seems that `tomcat` is redirecting to `login` instead of `/login`. Use:

```
ProxyPass / ajp://server.ip.address:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://server.ip.address:8009/
```

Comment: This helps me understand that tomcat is just concatenating a string, then passing the assembled string into another function.